# Error running call reference function for resource es_extended fiveM

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

Basically have another fivem es_extended issue where I am getting unwelcome errors everytime users try and join my server and show their money as undefined, and also not allow them to save their clothing.

I've dropped tables from my database and re-added them to no avail.

```
stack traceback:
        @es_extended/server/main.lua:155: in upvalue 'ref'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:391: in function <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:390>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:390: in function <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:389>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:405: in function <citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:374>
Error: Unhandled error in timer: Error: BUFFER_SHORTAGE
Error: BUFFER_SHORTAGE
    at n.e [as reserve] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:12766)
    at h (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:15761)
    at n.r [as decode] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:13908)
    at n.fetch (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:6972)
    at n.u [as read] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:12076)
    at Object.n [as decode] (citizen:/scripting/v8/msgpack.js:29:7097)
    at unpack (citizen:/scripting/v8/main.js:20:33)
    at citizen:/scripting/v8/main.js:51:20
    at setImmediate (mysql-async.js:4962:9)
    at Object.callback (citizen:/scripting/v8/timer.js:96:21)
```

Expected should be no errors at all, and thats the error messages that come along when a new person joins the server for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

All ESX 1.* are officially discontinued due to bugs in latest versions, based on ESX recommendations you can try [Extended Mode](https://github.com/extendedmode/extendedmode), works fine with minimum amount of bugs

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/).